# Specific counting once vector is filled with zero int and positive int

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `vector<int> count` which i `push_back` integers to, it is filled like this:

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1,2,3,4,5**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**6,7,8**,0,0,0,0,**9,10**,0,0,0

I want to go trough this vector and it should give `int counts = 3`, basically count how many positive integers there are between the zeros and count it as 1 per group.

Tried to loop trough all the elements the whole day and try different approaches but now I am giving up, therefore help would be appreciated!

[image: vector]

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Use a flag and set it to false.  Go through the vector element by element.  Once you find a non 0 and the flag is false set the flag to true and increment a counter.  Once you hit a zero set the flag back to false. keep going until you find another non 0 and do the same process.

Comment: [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) can be used for finding group borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through the elements in the vector and count the group if the previous value is zero as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int countGroups(vector<int> intVec)
{
    int count = 0;
    int vec_size = intVec.size();

    bool lastelemzero = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < vec_size; i++)
    {
        if((intVec[i]) && (lastelemzero))
        {
            count++;
            lastelemzero = false;
        }

        if(intVec[i] == 0)
            lastelemzero = true;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> count;

    count.push_back(0);
    count.push_back(0);
    count.push_back(1);
    count.push_back(2);
    count.push_back(3);
    count.push_back(0);
    count.push_back(0);
    count.push_back(0);
    count.push_back(10);
    count.push_back(20);
    count.push_back(0);
    count.push_back(0);
    count.push_back(1);
    count.push_back(2);
    count.push_back(3);
    count.push_back(0);
    count.push_back(0);

    cout << "number of groups : " << countGroups(count) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Many many THANKS! Wish I could buy you a beer :)

Comment: Thanks HumbleMan :)